# how to generate a control dynamically and give it specific caliburn properties?

Tags: c#, xaml, caliburn.micro, caliburn

We conntect our ViewModels with our Views via the Caliburn Framework.

Now I need to generate a `ListBox` dynamically via codebehind. Something like this:

```
this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(new ListBox() { Width = 800, ... });
```

Currently I declare this `ListBox` explicitly in the Xaml. Because I use Caliburn for placing dialogs, we have a

```
<silverlightToolkit:TransitioningContentControl caliburn:View.Model="{Binding ViewModel}" />
```

within this `ListBox`. How to generate this one? And the most important question: am I able to attatch the `caliburn:View.Model` property? Like I did it with the `Width` property on the `ListBox`? This `TransitioningContentControl` is nested in the `DataTemplate` of the `ListBoxItem`. Is it even possible to generate this via codebehind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in my codebehind looked like this:

```
var content = new TransitioningContentControl();
var newBinding = new Binding
                     {
                         // ...
                     };
content.SetBinding(View.ModelProperty, newBinding);
```

One has to insert `using Caliburn.Micro;`, though.